# Bad sector repair on root-drive

Tags: xubuntu, fsck

The utility Gnome-Disks report for my Xubuntu system: 41 bad sectors.

So I start up with a live-cd, logged in as root on the terminal and say run: fsck /dev/sda1 and the output is:

`/dev/sda1: clean.`

Is there a real bad sector problem?

---

Running `fsck -f /dev/sda1`:

```
root@xubuntu:~# fsck -f /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1 e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018) 
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes 
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts 
Pass 5: Checking group
summary information /dev/sda1: 232263/14655488 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 3171015/58607360 blocks 
root@xubuntu:~#
```

I think the mentioned problems by Gnome disks is not an issue. The second scan reports no problems, So I think everything is OK.

The result of e2fsck -c devsda1

```
root@xubuntu:~# e2fsck -c /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errdone                                                 
/dev/sda1: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 232348/14655488 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 3171431/58607360 blocks
root@xubuntu:~#
```

---

Update based on comments:

Thanks for your support Charles, I think the mentioned problems by Gnome disks is not an issue. The second scan reports no problems, So I think everything is OK. It seems that I respond not properly, I don't understand how to do it on the right way. I hope this is ok.
The result of e2fsck -c devsda1

root@xubuntu:~# e2fsck -c /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errdone
/dev/sda1: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 232348/14655488 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 3171431/58607360 blocks
root@xubuntu:~#

Comment: Sometimes the superblock of the partition is marked as clean even though there is an error.  You can force fsck to run a check with `fsck -f /dev/sda1`

Comment: You can also call for a scan of badblocks on your device with `e2fsck -c /dev/sda1`

Comment: The result of fsck -f /dev/sda1: root@xubuntu:~# fsck -f /dev/sda1 fsck from util-linux 2.31.1 e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018) 
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes 
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts 
Pass 5: Checking group summary information /dev/sda1: 232263/14655488 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 3171015/58607360 blocks root@xubuntu:~# 

Is this still OK ?

Comment: This output looks OK - you can try the `e2fsck -c /dev/sda1` to cause a scan for bad blocks - again this must be run  from a live USB.  More information about the process can be found in `man badblocks`

Comment: Please use the question to add well formatted extra info, mark it as "code" to keep textual formatting. Do not include lengthy things in comments. "edit" your posting to see how I did it.

Comment: Thanks for your support Charles, I think the mentioned problems by Gnome disks is not an issue. The second scan reports no problems, So I think everything is OK.
It seems that I respond not properly, I don't understand how to do it on the right way.

Comment: There's a bit of a learning curve.  Posting data be editing your answer (and formatting it) makes it both easier to read, and searchable.  If both of these scans have not turned up errors, I would not be too worried, but then again I also keep dual backups weekly, and have two more that are slower turnover!